# Insert Query in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[a and c variable's error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23dBr.png)Not inserting properly, Invalid column or can't convert to char from int if I add '' to it. Also Hardcoding a value in the string makes it work there.

" and ' have been tried..

```
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);

            string a3 = a.ToString();
            string c3 = c.ToString();

            string a2 = TextBox1.Text;
            string c2 = TextBox3.Text;

            int i1 = 77;
            int i2 = 5;

            string b = TextBox2.Text;
            string d = TextBox4.Text;
            string ee = TextBox5.Text;
            string f = TextBox6.Text;
            string g = TextBox7.Text;
            string h = TextBox8.Text;


            //RETRIVE VALUES FROM CURRENT BOXES
            //(Id,Username,Age,Gender,Contact,Email,City,Password)
            string update = dbhelper.ExecuteScalar("INSERT INTO 
            dbo.UserDetails VALUES(a,'b',c,'d','ee','f','g','h') ");

            Action_Performed.Text = "User Details Updated Successfully";
```

Comment: First thing is this isn't going to work. You are only executing a string. None of this references any of the variables. So if the first column is an int, it's going to try to insert a, which doesn't exist anywhere in your sql from ExecuteScalar.

Comment: The proper way to add values to a SQL command is to use a parameterized query, as shown [here](http://bobby-tables.com/adodotnet).

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it by doing something like this, important to use SQL parameters to avoid sql injection through your inputs;

```
string sql =  "INSERT INTO UserDetails(a,b,c) VALUES(@a,@b,@c)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", c);
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```